# Find and Replace in Xcode Using Regular Expression

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm wondering, is there a way that you can do a search for all words that have the word "pPath" in them and replace them with "mutablePath" in Xcode. For instance, there are certain instances where there could be pPath_0 or pPath_50, I just want to replace them all with "mutablePath". Is there a regular expression I can use for this if it's possible?

EDIT #1: I mean to actually replace the whole word pPath_50 or (any word that has pPath in it) with mutablePath. Doing a simple find and replace will only replace the word "pPath" with "mutablePath".

EDIT #2: I found out that if you click the magnifying glass next to the search bar, then click "Show Find Options", you can select "Regular Expression" from a pull down menu and use it to do a search for a regular expression. I'm assuming that the regular expression language used for this is common to other things, does anyone know what the regular expression is to search for any word that has pPath at the beginning of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you actually can use regular expressions on find and replace in Xcode 4.3. Simply click on the magnifying glass next to the search box (or the area where you enter in the text to search). Select "Show Find Options", then under "Style" choose "Regular Expression". I'm not too familiar with regular expressions, but I believe it uses syntax that is similar to a lot of other modules that implement them. For instance, I was able to solve my problem using "pPath_\w*".

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Go to Search Navigator (left pane) - Click on the drop down for 'Find' and you will see replace.

Comment: Yes I know that, but that in itself won't help me accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish. If I do a find for pPath and replace it with mutablePath, it only replace the part of the word that has "pPath" in it, not the entire word.